# Loading images programmatically

Tags: iphone

i want to load different images in different screens depending on some action performed on some screen.That is depending on the action performed on one screen it calciulates some result and based on that it should load images on different screens.but this should happen onLoad.
can anyone give me some solution

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple using [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).